# populate ng-bind-html from templateURL or any html template source

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have tabs controller:

```
$scope.tabs = [
    { template:'modules/order/views/estimates-list.html', heading: 'View Estimates', route:'default.order.info.estimates.list', active:false },
    { template:'modules/order/views/estimates-create.html', heading: 'Create New Estimate', route:'default.order.info.estimates.create', active:false },
];
```

Here on active the tab the following template is loading:

`estimates-create.html`

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <div ng-bind-html="myHTML">
        <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj"> ... </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am in need that ng-bind-html element will be initialized from one angular-html-template file or it will have the html as it is now.
But the problem is that `$scope.myHTML` is reset on opening the tab.
So how can I populate the `$scope.myHTML` in the template from a file(`template.html`) or keep the html in the `ng-bind-html="myHTML"` as it is after initializing?

`template.html`

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj"> ... </div>
```

Comment: Please explain this issue..can't understand..

Comment: @Vijay I need to populate html in `<div ng-bind-html="myHTML">` using either using templateURL or need to retain its content as it is now, e.g, `<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj"> ... </div>`
Let me know if you understood